# react wait for component to get state from store then render child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i am using react redux. In this Profiles component i use this.startSetUsers in componentWillMount to trigger fetching users from the mongodb and store it to state. then i mapStateToProps to get users from state as props, so i get this.props.users. 
Then in render i try to pass users as props to ProfilesList component and render that or if no users render no users from Profile component.

Now this works if state is empty and i navigate to ProfilesList or if i refresh that particular url with ProfilesList component but if go to ProfilePage component where through startSetUser i get only one user in state and show it in ProfilePage and then from that component where now state has one user i try to go to ProfilesList via < Link> show all users < /Link> i get an error "this.props.users.map is not a function" and i guess that is because mapStateToProps isnt finished before rendering and using this.props.users.map

i hope someone understood me, this was a bit mouthful. :D is there some work around this?

```
class Profiles extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.startSetUsers()
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="content-container content-container--list">
      <div className="list-header">
        <div className="show-for-mobile">Users</div>
        <div className="show-for-desktop">User</div>
        <div className="show-for-desktop">Joined</div>
      </div>
      <div className="list-body">
        {this.props.users.length === 0 ? (
          <div className="list-item list-item--message">
              <span>No users</span>
            </div>
        ) : (
          this.props.users.map((user) => {
            return <ProfilesList key={user._id} {...user} />
          })
        )
      }
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  users: state.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Profiles)
```

ProfilesList

```
const ProfilesList = ({ username, email, created_at, avatar }) => (
    <Link className="list-item" to={`/user/${username}`}>
      <div className="list-item__avatar-title">
        <div  className="list-item__avatar">
          <img src={avatar || 'https://image.ibb.co/bUv8k7/NoImage.png'} />
        </div>
        <div>
        <h3 className="list-item__title">{username}</h3>
        <span className="list-item__sub-title">{email}</span>
        <br />
        <span className="list-item__sub-title">List of articles: X</span>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4 className="list-item__joined">{moment(created_at).format('MMMM Do, YYYY')}</h4>
      </div>
    </Link>
)

export default ProfilesList;
```

Profile

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      usersLoaded: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
     this.props.startSetUser(this.props.match.params.id)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {
          this.props.user && this.props.match.params.id ?
          <ProfilePage {...this.props}/> :
          <div>404</div>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  user: state.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Profile)
```

ProfilePage

```
const ProfilePage = props => {
  const {user} = props;

  return (
    <div className="section">
      <div className="profile__header">
        <div className="profile__name">
          <h2>{`${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`}</h2>
          <h3>{user.email}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="profile__content">
            <div className="photo-container">
              <div className="photo">
                <img src={user.avatar || 'https://image.ibb.co/bUv8k7/NoImage.png'} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="profile__info">
              <p>Username: <strong>{user.username}</strong></p>
              <li>Email: <strong>{user.email}</strong></li>
              <li>Location: <strong>{user.location}</strong></li>
              <li>City: <strong>{user.city || renderMessage}</strong></li>
              <li>Birthday: <strong>{`${user.day} ${user.month}, ${user.year}`}</strong></li>
              <li>Gender: <strong>{user.gender}</strong></li>
              <li>Joined: <strong>{moment(user.created_at).format('MMMM Do, YYYY')}</strong></li>
            </div>
            <div className="profile__button">
              <button className="button">Edit</button>
              <Link to="/users" className="button">List of all users</Link>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;
```

reducer

```
const userReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER':
      return action.user;
    case 'SET_USERS':
      return action.users;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userReducer;
```

edit: forgot to post action

```
// SET_USER
export const setUser = (user) => ({
  type: 'SET_USER',
  user
})

export const startSetUser = (username) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/user/${username}`)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setUser(response.data))
      })
  }
}

// SET_USERS ALL
export const setUsers = (users) => ({
  type: 'SET_USERS',
  users
})

export const startSetUsers = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/users`)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setUsers(response.data))
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's an issue with your reducer:

```
const userReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER':
      return action.user;
    case 'SET_USERS':
      return action.users;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userReducer;
```

You are overwriting `state` with `action.user` and `action.users`. I'm going to guess that `action.user` is an object and `action.users` is an array. So when `ProfileList` renders, it sees that `this.state.users` exists, BUT you set it to an object instead of an array.

I would make a new property in the `userReducer` for `activeUser` or make a new reducer to handle saving the active user.

```
const initialState = {
    activeUser: null,
    users: []
};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER':
      state.activeUser = action.user;
      return state;
    case 'SET_USERS':
      state.users = action.users
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chase, you got me thinking in right direction, i've managed to find solution, the reducer was the problem indeed

i've changed the reducer to this

```
const userReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER':
      return { ...state, user: action.payload }
    case 'SET_USERS':
      return { ...state, users: action.payload }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userReducer;
```

and it works:)

alose here is the action that i changed to work with newly changed reducer

```
// SET_USER
export const setUser = (user) => ({
  type: 'SET_USER',
  payload: user
})

export const startSetUser = (username) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/user/${username}`)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setUser(response.data))
      })
  }
}

// SET_USERS ALL
export const setUsers = (users) => ({
  type: 'SET_USERS',
  payload: users
})

export const startSetUsers = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/users`)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setUsers(response.data))
      })
  }
}
```